# tornado websocket server - connections queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, tornado, python-multithreading

I have a `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler` which processes data. The idea is to instantiate a limited number of handlers (e.g. so they are bounded by the the number of CPU cores). I would like to put the rest of the connections in a queue (as soon as they are opened) so one of them is activated when another finishes.

I was trying to do that via `threading.Semaphore`, but it seems that tornado socket handlers run in a single thread, so everything hangs out. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

Tornado has its own [asynchronous semaphore class](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/locks.html#semaphore) in `tornado.locks.Semaphore`.

Tornado is designed to make connections very cheap - one connection per core would be an extremely low limit. I suggest not limiting the number of connections per se, but limiting what you do with these connections. (and remember the GIL - unless you're calling out to C extensions for your cpu-intensive work, you can't make use of multiple CPU cores from python anyway). Doing your CPU-intensive work on a bounded ThreadPoolExecutor may be the best way to do what it sounds like you're trying to do.